# HBase not connecting to ZooKeeper

Tags: hadoop

I am not able to connect to HBase shell on my local Ubuntu machine. Tried to look all across internet. Not getting what's wrong. In the logs I keep getting this error -

```
zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: Unable to create ZooKeeper Connection.
```

**hbase-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>    
    <value>hdfs://localhost:54310/hbase</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>/home/hduser/zookeeper</value>
  </property>

  <property>
      <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
      <value>2222</value>
      <description>Property from ZooKeeper's config zoo.cfg.
      The port at which the clients will connect.
      </description>
  </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
      <value>localhost</value>
      <description>Comma separated list of servers in the ZooKeeper Quorum.
      </description>
    </property>

</configuration>
```

**core-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
  <value>/app/hadoop/tmp</value>
  <description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://localhost:54310</value>
  <description>The name of the default file system.</description>
</property>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you are using non-default port for zookeper , makesure you have same in zookeeper configuration file , **zoo.cfg** 
as 
    clientPort=2222

also make sure your **hbase-env.sh** file has below line.

```
export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=true
```

also for ubuntu make sure your **/etc/hosts** file doesnt have loopback issue.
it should have a line similar to below.

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering. I was using a different version of HBase which was meant for Hadoop 1. But I ran into a different error. Please have a look. I highly appreciate your help.

http://askubuntu.com/questions/599334/the-node-hbase-unsecure-is-not-in-zookeeper-check-the-value-configured-in-zoo