# The node /hbase-unsecure is not in ZooKeeper. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'

Tags: hadoop

I am getting this error while starting standalone hBase on my ubuntu machine. Please help. Spent a huge amount of time to get it running. :(

What I have checked so far -

1. /etc/hosts contains localhost 127.0.0.1
2. HBase : hbase-0.98.3-hadoop2-bin.tar.gz
3. Hadoop: hadoop-2.6.0.tar.gz
4. I already have the node /hbase-unsecure in my hbase-site.xml.

When I try to run the command - create 'usertable', 'resultfamily'

It gives me following exception -

ERROR: The node /hbase-unsecure is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>    
    <value>hdfs://localhost:54310/hbase</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>/home/hduser/zookeeper</value>
  </property>

  <property>
      <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
      <value>2181</value>
      <description>Property from ZooKeeper's config zoo.cfg.
      The port at which the clients will connect.
      </description>
  </property>

  <property>
        <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>

   <property>
        <name>zookeeper.znode.parent</name>
        <value>/hbase-unsecure</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
      <value>localhost</value>
      <description>Comma separated list of servers in the ZooKeeper Quorum.
      </description>
    </property>

  <property>
         <name>dfs.replication</name>
         <value>1</value>
    </property>

  <property>
        <name>hbase.master</name> 
        <value>hadoop-master:60000</value>
  </property>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

did you clean up zookeeper data directory from previous trials ? by default `zookeeper.znode.parent` is /hbase ,

options you can try

1. if you are changing it intentionally then changing zookeeper data directory when changing it. In ***/home/hduser/zookeeper***
2. try changing znode.parent to /hbase

Comment: God bless you Ratnakar.

Comment: I was just a newbie and got it all mixed up from various Stack Overflow posts. So the problem with me was, I was not having /hbase-unsecure location in my root directory.

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same issue. I need to know where was the /hbase-unsecure created? what do you mean root directory? whose root directory? HBase's or Zookeeper's. I have one in both and I am facing this issue.

Comment: Hi Sankalp am facing the same problem. which root location are you talking abt? can you give us steps to do it